# Optimizing the way params are sent to multiple methods

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

I have a singleton instance of an object which has a method `m1`that calls `m2`, which calls `m3` ... and so on till `m10`.

There are a set of parameters which I send to `m1` and are used only by `m10`. But I end up passing those params to `m2`...`m9` even though they are not being used by these methods. I can also not call `m10` directly from `m1` because `m10` needs some other params that are built on the way.

The problem is that I don't want to pass these unnecessary params to each of the methods every time, especially when its not going to be used inside. Is there way to get rid of this problem using closures?

```
  var singleTon = function(){};

    singleTon.prototype.m1 = function(a,b,c){
      this.m2(a,b,c);
    };

    singleTon.prototype.m2 = function(a,b,c){
      this.m3(a,b,c);
    };

    ... //Goes on till m9

    singleTon.prototype.m10 = function(a,b,c,d,e){

       //Perform some operations with a,b,c,d,e

    };
```

Comment: I'm confused if you are passing the exact same params every time, or not. But if you are, have you looked into using `Function.prototype.apply`? It would allow you to call a method with the `arguments` object, without explicitly naming each - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply . Hopefully I'm not misunderstanding

Comment: Why don't you make these parameters properties of the object and inject them as you need?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos If I make them properties of the object then their scope becomes the scope of this singleton object which is the scope of the entire app's life. I want it's scope to be each call of the `m1` method.

Comment: @Ian 1. Yes I am passing the same params everytime. 2. Can you give an example of what you are saying using some code?

Comment: @Tushar, you can inject the dependencies on demand and clear them when you don't need them anymore...

Comment: @Tushar Hopefully this makes sense and helps: http://jsfiddle.net/fQJBV/

Comment: @Tushar, I think the problem is with your architecture. You are breaking the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). You should consider refactoring this.

Comment: @Ian I am somehow not able to open the link. Can you post the code in the answers also?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which is via using lodash's [bindKey](http://lodash.com/docs#bindKey) method. It is doing exactly what I require.